# events for right click detection in Outlook and Power point

Tags: outlook, contextmenu, powerpoint, right-click

In office applications i want to get the word on which the user right clicks.

i was able to get for Excel and Word. in outlook and PowerPoint i am not able detect the right click event.

In outlook i want to detect right click on a word in mail body.
In power point i want to detect right click in a slide content.

In outlook i have tried the events:
ItemContextMenuDisplay,
AttachmentContextMenuDisplay,
FolderContextMenuDisplay,
ContextMenuClose,
StoreContextMenuDisplay,
ViewContextMenuDisplay,

In power point i have tried:
WindowBeforeRightClick,

can somebody help me with the events to be used?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer the Outlook part.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any events for that. The only possible solution is to add your control to the context menu and handle the getVisible or getEnabled callbacks. Thus, you will be aware when the context menu is going to be displayed. But it seems MS doesn't provide the required IDs for that menu, see [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforMultipleSelectedItems) for more information.

See [Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

Comment: I followed the links above. but is there way to get contetmenu using ribbon UI? I am trying to prepare a shared addin which can detect patterns in all office applications. so on right click of a text i want to read the word and process and show the context menu accordingly. is it possible to do for office 2013? any idea on this

Comment: See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of PowerPoint, WindowBeforeRightClick is the correct event.

You would find that setting **Cancel = True** in the handler for that event only works if the right-click is on the slide itself. On a shape or within a text range this fails to work as expected.

Workaround is the lock the screen and switch to a different view and back and then update the screen to prevent the contextual menu from appearing for the shape/text range.

Comment: Hi Shyam, thanks for replying. could you please elaborate "Workaround is the lock the screen and switch to a different view and back and then update the screen to prevent the contextual menu from appearing for the shape/text range." . I didnt got how to start for it.